# Accessing the data of other users using access delegation in Android

Tags: android, authentication, delegation

I am stuck with a scenario here and I would like to know the possible solutions to handle it.

I am building an android application which will try to fetch the health data from a third party health API like Google Fit, Runkeeper, etc. Now, I have the scenario where Device A (a smartphone running my android application) of User A wants to access the health data of Device B (another smartphone running my android application) of User B.

To put it in more simpler context, User A will approach User B asking its health data. User B provides the permission and User A should now be able to access the health data of User B directly from the third party health APIs (like Google Fit, Runkeeper, etc).I would like to know the various possibilities of achieving the same.  Also, please feel free to add in the links that discusses about a similar situation with possible solutions like building authentication servers, access delegation, etc.

**Further info:**

I did not wanted the data(retrieved from third party APIs) to be duplicated once again in another server. Hence, I wanted to go by the access delegation strategy.

Now, I would like to compare the scenario with the OAuth authentication. OAuth allows for identity delegation. Identity delegation allows a resource provider (such as Facebook) to be informed of the fact that a resource owner (a particular user in Facebook) allows a third-party (some application other than Facebook) to access and/or change the data belonging to the resource owner that is stored with the resource provider (such as allowing the third-party application to update the user’s Facebook status or get a list with the user’s friends). Reference: http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/securing-web-apis-part-ii-creating-an-api-authenticated-with-oauth-2-in-node-js/

Now, comparing this to my scenario, the 'resource owner' is 'User B' and the 'third party application' is equivalent to 'User A'. And the 'resource provider' is the 'health API' which contains the user health data. So, adding to my exact question posted above, I would also like to know the feasibility of using OAuth authentication delegation strategies here.

Comment: I don't think that is implemented in those services, but I might be wrong. A solution would be to have your server in the middle storing the data and sharing, but for privacy settings you have to be careful

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my content and updated further info.